# ScrollView is not scrolling?

Tags: android

Ok I am trying to create a screen with a lot of buttons on it, obviously I ran out of space so I set my layout to a ScrollView with a relative layout underneath it and then placed all of my buttons inside that.

heres the code:

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1000dp" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.cecode.www.gjcode.MainTypes"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Options Menu(placeholder)"
        android:id="@+id/optionsBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Top Text"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="placeholder text"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="placeholder text"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="placeholder text"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="mid text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/optionsBtn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/optionsBtn"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="bottom text"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

heres a screenshot of the screen-

[image: Scrollview screenshot]

My problem is that when I test this on a device it will not scroll past the mid text point, so I cannot get to the bottom text bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
android:layout_height="1000dp"
```

with

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

and let me know if it works

ok as you specified as per your requirement you can use LinearLayout with verticla orientation and between mid and bottom text put another linear layout with wrap_content height to add your buttons if you want some space before adding buttons to it you can specify minheight to layout take look at below code

```
<ScrollView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context="com.cecode.www.gjcode.MainTypes"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Options Menu(placeholder)"
        android:id="@+id/optionsBtn"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Top Text"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"

        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="placeholder text"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="placeholder text"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="placeholder text"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="mid text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
         />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:minHeight="50dp"
          android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- add your button here -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="bottom text"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: When I do this the bottom text will surge back up to the base screen and all the space between mid text and bottom text will be lost. The idea being that the space between Mid and Bottom text will be occupied by buttons.

Comment: i dont understand what you want to achive the space between midtext and bottom text is fixed or you want to add some items there or else

Comment: Ok, what I want to do is add buttons between the space from mid to bottom(and expand it if I need more buttons) on the users end they would scroll down to see said buttons.

Comment: @ParagonTime check my updated answer you will get an idea

Answer (score 1):

it is really hard to catch your requirements. Let me explain how it works at the moment. ScrollView doesn't give exact height so when you set match_parent for relative layout I guess it sets max height for this view - Integer.MAX_VALUE. That is why Android Studio warns you to change match_parent to wrap_content. 
If you need this view in the bottom - set the margin of your bottom view in runtime.